# Mobicents application router not routing external IP INVITE

Tags: jboss7.x, mobicents, mobicents-sip-servlets

I am using Mobicents on Jboss 7.2.
My Mobicents seems doesn't passes messages to the application if the soft-phone is on another machine.

```
I'm executing the server as "./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0"
```

The both phone are registered to the server but:

1. If I call from the phone from another machine it calls, but INVITE isn't passed to my app.
2. If I call from a phone in the same machine on the server the INVITE is delivered to my app but the INVITE from my app to external phone isn't delivered.

As DAR I have:

```
OPTIONS: ("org.mobicents.servlet.sip.example.SimpleApplication", "DAR:From", "ORIGINATING", "", "NO_ROUTE", "0") 
REGISTER: ("org.mobicents.servlet.sip.example.SimpleApplication", "DAR:From", "ORIGINATING", "", "NO_ROUTE", "0") 
INVITE: ("org.mobicents.servlet.sip.example.SimpleApplication", "DAR:From", "ORIGINATING", "", "NO_ROUTE", "0")
```

How it can be? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to retry with a recent build from https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/MobicentsSipServlets-Release/. There was some fixes recently to the 0.0.0.0 binding. If that still doesn't work please provide the logs at DEBUG level for categories org.mobicents and gov.nist (in standalone-sip.mml)

Comment: Hi Jeand. I've updated mobicent but I have always the same problem. When I call from "sip:user1@10.1.2.84:5061" that is the same IP of the machine in which there is Mobicents, the sip servlet catch the INVITE but a second invite from the servlet to the remote phone isn't sent. 
If i try to do the reverse, no message arrives to Mobicents log but the call yes, so the connection can be established.

This is a folder with de Log that you asked me. I hope it can be useful to understand where I'm wrong

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ki775il04z9aifq/AAA-hHGm-9zW8lPwu7BC7Vena?dl=0

Comment: The logs you provided are at INFO Level not DEBUG level as asked in my previous answer. Please re record the failing calls with logging categories org.mobicents and gov.nist  and root logger  level in standalone-sip.xml set at DEBUG. Also please try to bind directly to the real IP of the network interface instead of 0.0.0.0 to see if that works better ?

Comment: Forgive me I made a mistake! I will provide you the correct log ASAP.

Comment: Hello Jeand, only now I back to work to mobicents project. At the moment I have mobicents installed on a linux machine and a client with two softphones. This is the link to the debug file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1yi33zsaz87aih/debug-mobicents.js?dl=0